# PropertyBuilder: IsRequired(false) vs not adding it at all

Tags: ef-core-5.0

In EF Core 5 the class `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.PropertyBuilder` has the method `IsRequired(bool required = true)` which can be used to configure properties of entities.

Is there any difference if I add `IsRequired(false)` to a property in the entity configuration or if I don't add `IsRequired()` at all?